# How to display C++ STL Containers in GDB/Nemiver in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, stl, gdb

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) and gdb 7.3 / Nemiver 0.8.2.
I'd like to display content of STL containers, but so far I've been not *really* successful.

Is there any other visual debugger (better based on gdb) I should be using to display the STL containers variables?
I'm looking for a solution which supports composition of containers (i.e. `std::map<int, std::vector< std::pair< ... > > >`).

Cheers

Comment: It's actually not really _usable_ to be quite frank. If I have to use a poor visual debugger, I think I'd be better off with bare gdb then. Cheers

Comment: There is also `insight`, and the debugging environment that comes with `eclipse`. But I think both are again wrappers over `gdb` (like `DDD`).

Comment: Recent GDB (a.g. 7.4) are scriptable with Python, and recent GCC -eg 4.7- (and their stdc++ library) may even provide the relevant scripts to nicely display C++ standard containers.

Comment: You can always write a .dump() for your container/class.

Answer (score 0):

New enough versions of GDB support a pretty-printing API from Python.  This lets applications provide Python code to customize some aspects of the display of objects.  This code is designed to work with both the CLI ("print" at the gdb prompt) and MI (the interface that GUIs use, or at least ought to use).

New enough versions of GCC ship Python pretty-printers for all important data structures in libstdc++.

The last step is to get a new-enough version of nemiver.  I think 0.9.2 has this feature.

Many distros ship gdb and gcc set up so that the pretty-printers are automatically activated if your program uses libstdc++.  So, maybe just upgrading nemiver would be sufficient for you.  Otherwise, there are plenty of docs online about how to set this up.

Comment: Specifically which version include all of this for gdb/gcc?

Comment: You need at least gdb 7.0 -- though newer is better, since there have been bug fixes, etc.  Also it must be built with the Python support enabled.  I forget which version of GCC first shipped the pretty-printers.  4.5 or 4.6 I think.  You can look for a file named "printers.py" in the source or install trees.

Answer (score 0):

Download the following file -

https://github.com/jgarvin/joe-etc/blob/master/gdb/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb

From GDB -

```
# source <PATH>/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb

# pmap <map-object> <key-type> <value-type>
```

...